# OData V4 client adding child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, odata-v4

I have a parent (Order) and child (OrderDetail) where Order already exists in the database and OrderDetail also exists in the database.
All I really want to do is add another OrderDetail record bound to the Order.

I have been down several paths and I'm not even sure what is the correct path.
Let's make some assumptions that navigations between these are already working.
I can $expand=OrderDetails fine and I can also Orders(1)/OrderDetails fine and do the reverse from OrderDetails.

Based on this [**Updating the Data Service**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361(v=vs.110).aspx), all I need to do is call AddRelatedObject and then Add the object to the OrderDetails collection.

```
// Add the new item with a link to the related Order
context.AddRelatedObject(order, "OrderDetails", newOrderDetail);
// Add the new order detail to the collection
order.Order_Details.Add(newOrderDetail);
newOrderDetail.Order = order;
```

Seems simple enough.
Yet when I execute context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate) it will throw an error.

> {"error":{"code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Test/odata/Orders(1)/OrderDetails'.","innererror":{"message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation'.","type":"","stacktrace":""}}}

But if I navigate to the URL listed, it shows data.
Time for Fiddler.
In Fiddler, I can see this is a POST to the URL and not a GET.
Which it should be a POST but not to the URL listed.
The POST should have been to /odata/OrderDetails

**Round 2**

```
// Add the new item with a link to the related Order
context.AttachTo("OrderDetails", newOrderDetail);
// Add a link between Order and the new OrderDetail
context.AddLink(order, "OrderDetails", newOrderDetail);
// Add the new order detail to the collection
order.Order_Details.Add(newOrderDetail);
newOrderDetail.Order = order;
```

Still a POST with an error but the URL is slightly different and the json posted only has "/odata/OrderDetail(0)" it also now has "$ref".

> {"error":{"code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Test/odata/Orders(1)/OrderDetails/$ref'.","innererror":{"message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation/$ref'.","type":"","stacktrace":""}}}

Well a quick web search led me to this article [**Entity Relations in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2**](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4)
This article says I need to add a "CreateRef" in the Orders controller.
I did create a "CreateRef" in the Orders controller and sure enough it gets called BUT the article assumes the OrderDetail exists in the database.
It is not posting the json OrderDetail object.

**Round 3**

```
// Add the new item with a link to the related Order
context.AttachTo("OrderDetails", newOrderDetail);
// Attach a link between Order and the new OrderDetail
context.AttachLink(order, "OrderDetails", newOrderDetail);
// Add the new order detail to the collection
order.Order_Details.Add(newOrderDetail);
newOrderDetail.Order = order;
```

Well this seems much better.
No error but it did not fully work.
It sent a PUT to the /odata/OrderDetails(0) and it did send the json OrderDetail object BUT this should have been a **POST not a PUT**.

I feel I am so close yet I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I found something that worked.

```
// create a new order detail
OrderDetail newOrderDetail = new OrderDetail();
// set the orderID on the new order detail
newOrderDetail.OrderID = order.ID;
// add the order back as a link on the order detail
newOrderDetail.Order = order;
// add the order detail to the order detail collection on the order
order.OrderDetails.Add(newOrderDetail);
// add the order detail to the context
context.AddToOrderDetail(newOrderDetail);
// now update context for the order
context.UpdateObject(order);
// now save
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution today.

Take a look at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/457028 :

> There is no inbuilt convention to handle POST requests to ~/entityset(key)/navigation. You have to build one yourself. Check out this [a sample code](https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/5903008) for that.

You need first to create a `EntitySetRoutingConvention` :

```
public class CreateNavigationPropertyRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/key/navigation" && controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            IEdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty = (odataPath.Segments[2] as NavigationPathSegment).NavigationProperty;
            controllerContext.RouteData.Values["key"] = (odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment).Value; // set the key for model binding.
            return "PostTo" + navigationProperty.Name;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, you have to register it in `WebApiConfig.Register`:

```
var routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
routingConventions.Insert(0, new CreateNavigationPropertyRoutingConvention());
server.Configuration.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "", GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), routingConventions);
```

Please note this sample is for oData v3 but can easily be converted to v4.

Then, you'll just have to add your parent object to the context and use `AddRelatedObject` for all the children.
Your request will be send to this void in your `ParentController`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostToOrders([FromODataUri] int key, Order order)
    {
        // create order.
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, order);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but after trial and error I was able to find the answer. It was an issue on the client side in the way I was trying to add the child to the parent.