# Adding Child to an existing parent in Webapi odata controller

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, odata

I using Odata Webapi with EF6 and my models are as below

```
public class Company
{

Public Company()
{
Products = new List<Product>();

}
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }

public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I need to expose an end point to add product/s to an existing Company. 
the end point has to be something like below.

```
Post: ~odata/Company(1)/Products with body as List of products json.
body:[{"Name":"Product1"},{"Name":"Product2"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an bound ODataAction for this purpose.
You would need to pass in a DTO containing a list of Products.

An example for DTO would be:

```
public class CreateProductsDTO
{
 List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would need to register an bound action to Company controller:

```
var action = builder.EntityType<Company>().Action("AddProducts");
action.Parameter<CreateProductsDTO>("Value");
```

In the controller you need to define an action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddProducts([FromODataUri] Guid key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
  //read parameter from ODataActionParameters 
  var createProducts = parameters["Value"] as CreateProductsDTO;

  //Process information
}
```

The request for this would look like this:

```
Post: ~odata/Company(1)/AddProducts
body:
{ "Value" : {
"Products" : 
[{"Name":"Product1"},{"Name":"Product2"}]
}
}
```

Hope this helps.
Regards,
Mihai

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mihai , where should i add this line (var action = builder.EntityType<Company>().Action("AddProducts");
action.Parameter<CreateProductsDTO>("Value");) is it in WebapiConfig Register method towards ODataConventionModelBuilder (or ) DBModelbuilder. RegisterEntityType whole OnModelCreating.

Comment: hi, got where i should have the bound action. i am using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder and i dont have builder.EntityType. if i use System.Web.OData.Builder i cannot convert from 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel' to 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel'

Comment: Hi,
You are correct this should go in the ODataConventionModelBuilder
What version of OData are you using ?

Comment: Don't know if this will help but I posted a similar situation here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230498/odata-v4-client-adding-child-entity